# jQuery: preventDefault() not working on anchor link tag (tried many methods!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to prevent anchor link from sending to another page but it's not actually working, I don't even know whyyy. I used preventDefault before and it works every time but this time I don't know what's going on.

Yes i've seen this question on stackoverflow and tried all methods but it's still *not working*

**HTML Code:**

```
 <h2><a id="donta" href="/services.html">Eco Ideas</a></h2>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('#donta').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            alert(event.target.tagName);    //yes it alerts me 'A'

            if(event.isDefaultPrevented()){

                    alert('Prevented!');    //yes it shows this alert but still send me to that link

                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }else{

                    // NOPE, it doesn't show this "ELSE" part...means the below alert doesn't show up...means according to browser or jQuery it is now PREVENTED

                    alert('Not prevented but trying to prevent now');
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
            return false;
});
```

You can see I tried all methods, but still it send me to that damn link!
Thanks in advance, because I know you guys will find a way :)

Comment: The quoted code doesn't, of course, replicate the listed problem: https://jsfiddle.net/cf2dkz5d/ `preventDefault` is not broken. Please update the question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstraing the problem.

Comment: @gaetanoM: That's never necessary if you put your scripts in the right place *(he said with mock provocation **:-)** )*. But since the OP says he sees the alerts, we can assume the handler is hooked up.

Comment: @gaetanoM Yes it is wrapped in document ready event

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Is it working on your side? Damn! Just saw  that fiddle and it it working but why not working on my webpage?? I tried Hard reload and other one that is 'Empty cache and hard reload'...but still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it works. It does not follow the link. We can't answer the question of why it doesn't work on your page without seeing an example of what doesn't work.

Comment: @Tayyab So, like @"T.J. Crowder" wrote: please, create an evidence.

Comment: I edited my comment. As I mentioned, it is not working. Should I make a video on that to show you guys or something?

Comment: No, you should create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Read the link for the details of why that's important (not least because the process of creating one will probably show you what's wrong).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Look, i'm using gulp for automation my stuff and live reloading...maybe gulp is a problem? Because I tried my code once again by restarting gulp and hard reloading page but still it keeps sending me on that link. ... and the url is like "http://localhost:4040/"

Comment: I also tried my script on IE-11 browser and result is the ..it follows that link.

Comment: No, gulp or the URL will have no effect on this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Are you still here with me? I can create a temporary localhost website (using ngrok) so you can check it live...hmm?

Comment: **Again:** Create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and post it to the question. Use Stack Snippets so it's runnable. The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: here open this link...this is the site i'm working on...demo data in it...there is written ECO IDEAS... Click on that and you'll see... http://778de462.ngrok.io/app/html-starter/build/developing/

Comment: I know .. i've read that article...but still the problem isn't solved yet...and I gave you guys minimal code and all the stuff needed for this answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The link i provided used exact same code for preventing that link to send me on another page..but still it is not working

Comment: Do you have more than one link on your page with `id="donta"` ? Obviously this will cause problems.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: No it's the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of event-listeners on the link. And 2 of them are listening `click` event. It seems like while one prevent link, other one don't.

[image]

I think trouble may be in this function, because it triggers:

```
function end(e) {
  clearTimeout(resetTimer);
  resetTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    w.tapHandling = false;
    cancel = false;
  }, 1000);

  // make sure no modifiers are present. thx http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/click-events/
  if ((e.which && e.which > 1) || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) {
    return;
  }

  e.preventDefault();

  // this part prevents a double callback from touch and mouse on the same tap

  // if a scroll happened between touchstart and touchend
  if (cancel || w.tapHandling && w.tapHandling !== e.type) {
    cancel = false;
    return;
  }

  w.tapHandling = e.type;
  trigger(e);
}
```

Comment: Did you opened my scripts.min.js? There is only one function dealing with this ID.

Comment: And also can you provide me the Line number of this function you found..because I haven't created any fuction..probably an library of jQuery.??

Comment: Thanks man! i found which other function was messing with all 'a' tags. Now it works perfect!

Comment: You're welcome. And sorry I couldn't send you line number, because I was far from computer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually not set href attribute with value and just set `href="javascript:void(0)"` when I won't that link was redirected and will set action in that link.

Maybe will work for you too.

Comment: But what if there is a link in href attribute? Because you can't add "javascript:void(0)" in wordpress menu generated links.

Comment: I think we still can replace that attribute in state `document.ready` or `window.onload`